# Publishing to speech topic on the Nao

Tags: ros, nao-robot, nao-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to publish to the speech topic on using the nao_driver package.
What did I miss out?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

from dynamic_reconfigure.server import Server as ReConfServer
from nao_driver.cfg import nao_speechConfig as NodeConfig
from nao_driver import NaoNode
from naoqi import (ALBroker, ALProxy, ALModule)
from std_srvs.srv import( Empty, EmptyResponse )
from nao_msgs.msg import( WordRecognized )

def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('speech', String)
    rospy.init_node('talker')
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        str = "hello world %s" % rospy.get_time()
        rospy.loginfo(str)
        pub.Publish(String(str))
        rospy.sleep(1.0)
        
if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

The output on the console:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "rosout"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132171/publishing-to-speech-topic-on-the-nao./) by [dnth](https://answers.ros.org/users/11961/dnth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2014-02-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-02-24**:
This is looking good. Is the nao_speech node running and volume turned up? Check that your node properly connects to nao_speech with `rqt_graph`. Afaik you can ignore the "No handlers can be found..." error.

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-06-17**:
I tried to do this but the robot takes a lot of time to respond. I created a loop for publishing hello world over the speech topic and the robot responds very late the the first few hello worlds. Can u please help me?
http://answers.ros.org/question/171331/real-nao-robot-responding-very-slow-to-the-topic-published-with-ros/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got it working with the codes below. Hope this helps those who's trying to familiarize with programming the Nao on ROS

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def naotalker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', String)
    rospy.init_node('naotalk')
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        str = "hello world"
        rospy.loginfo(str)
        pub.publish(String(str))
        rospy.sleep(1.0)
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        naotalker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

---

Originally posted by [dnth](https://answers.ros.org/users/11961/dnth/) with karma: 106 on 2014-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-06-09**:
shouldnt you be publishing over the topic "speech" instead of the "chatter"? Can you please help me with my question here?
http://answers.ros.org/question/171331/real-nao-robot-responding-very-slow-to-the-topic-published-with-ros/